# CSS to style element before the hovered element?

Tags: html, css, hover

I want to change the style of any `div` which is **before** my `ul`:

```
<style>
ul:hover + #x {
    display:none;
}
</style>

<div id="x">c</div>

<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
</ul>
```

When I put the `div` after the `ul`, it works. (Sure, because the `+` in the CSS chooses all the #x **after** the `ul`.)

But I need to make it work the other way. I don't want to use JavaScript.

I can't put the `div` after the `ul`, because it would destroy every other style I've put in already.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: It's almost certainly impossible with CSS, as CSS can only select elements that appear  later in the DOM. But without knowing exactly what you want to do, we can't say for sure that it's impossible.

Comment: i am trying to have rows of 2 divs side by side and if you hover on the left element of a even row, on the right element there shall be displayed a text, and on the other side, when you hover the right element of an odd row, there shall be displayed the text on the left element of this odd row ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "previous sibling" selector in CSS. What you want can be accomplished using JavaScript, but as of now there is no pure CSS way of doing it.

This said, it isn't necessary for elements to appear in the order that they are marked up. You could put the `#x` div after the unordered list in your markup, and use CSS to make it appear before the list. This way you could still use the `+` selector for your purposes.

Comment: yeah thanks i figured out this way, so its impossible ...
my problem is that i have to change all css (floating etc.) to accomplish that, because i have positioned 2 divs side by side with float:left on the first div and overflow:hidden; on the second one, and then the width varies, but anyways i have to change it all, because i didnt know that this was impossible, argghhh :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are not completely against using JavaScript then you could add a `class` to all your `divs` before the `ul` tags and use CSS to style that `class`.

I assume that it's not practical to do this by the hard-coded way so you could use JavaScript to do it `onLoad`, that way the the script would run only once when the page is loaded and you avoid having an `event listener` bound to the `hover` event.